# When to split sub-apps into new apps

Tags: python, django, organization

I'm creating a film/tv related site: Films are referred to as 'titles', so I have a titles app to deal with the operations for those. However, titles can also have genres and cast members.

What is the best way to organize this? At the moment I have:

```
apps/titles (contains Title, and TitleGenre classes)
apps/titles/genres (contains Genre model class)
```

Is this the optimal solution? Sub-apps for `titles` may even be required, as for `genres`  Would the casting for similar ones be within the title app? I'd obviously like to start the best way before I delve any deeper.

Comment: The primary reason for splitting is when you think you can reuse this same subset of functionality in another projects. If not, just use standard python modules (for example, if your views.py is too big, convert it into a views directory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something along these lines:

```
MyProject/
|- films/
   |- __init__.py
   |- urls.py
   |- models/
      |- __init__.py
      |- genre.py
      |- actor.py
      |- title.py
      |- actorrole.py //M2M through with actors and their roles in specific titles
   |- admin/
      |- __init__.py
      |- genre.py
      |- actor.py
      |- title.py
   |- views/
      |- __init__.py
      |- someview.py
|- myproject/
   |- __init__.py
   |- urls.py
   |- wsgi.py
   |- settings/
      |- __init__.py
      |- production.py
      |- staging.py
      |- local.py
```

3 or 4 models isn't so many that I would spread this into several apps. BUT for organization, keep your models and admin classes in separate files and import them in the folder's `__init__.py`s

### important notes:

in your model make sure you include app_name in the inner Meta class.

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        app_label = _(u'films') #app's name
        ...
```

make sure that any FKs are passed as strings not as classes (helps avoid cyclic dependencies)

```
title = models.ForeignKey("films.Title")
```

in your `films/models/__init__.py` import in the  proper order so as not to have cyclic deps.

```
from films.models.genre import Genre
from films.models.actor import Actor
from films.models.title import Title
from films.models.actorrole import ActorRole
```

in your `films/admin/__init__.py` register each of your admin classes

```
from django.contrib import admin
from lottery.models import Genre, Actor, Title
from lottery.admin.actor import ActorAdmin

admin.site.register(Actor, ActorAdmin)
...
```

Comment: Great answer! You need to break down to packages contains modules for things just like this!